# What is the best practice/way to implement Toolbar in android apps Toolbar as Action Bar or Standalone Toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

Android's new Toolbar widgets class can be implemented as Action Bar or as a standalone Toolbar.I am confuse about which way is faster and recommended to use.

Comment: I believe there's no *better* way of doing it, the widget is to make it easier to have the action bar integrated in your apps. For instance I simply use a custom fragment for the action bar which, for my taste, gives me the control I need. This is primarily opinion based

Answer (score 2):

Well first I would like to say

A Toolbar is a generalization of `ActionBars` for use within application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework.

and I think you know all that already

**and then the most importance feature**

A Toolbar may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view hierarchy.

both way performance would be same but the thing is standalone Toolbar will be move able inside the view hierarchy so it all depends on what you wanna do with it if you need it just as action bar then use it as action bar and if you want to move it around like in `AppbarLayout` etc then set it as Toolbar.

Hope it helps